# How to disable this message in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

[image]Hi All,

Is there is a way to disable the option of presenting this message in Azure?
Is there's a policy that I need to configure NOT to show this message?

(i'm seeing this message in the file --> view/edit in (when i'm selecting the Image.

I've been trying to find the where can this policy be, but maybe there isn't one and I'm just wasting my time to find one.
But in the other hand it seems like this error is coming from somewhere...(right)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I also got the same error like below***

[image]

***Note***: This error is default Microsoft security notification you can't disable this message as there is an limit of editing file in azure portal. You can edit the file which is upto 2.1mb.

To confirm this, I try to edit file under 2.5mb error message doesn't appear I can able to edit the text file like below.

[image]

This limit is only for editing the text file not for uploading the file.

***Reference***:

[Scalability and performance targets for Blob storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/scalability-targets)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Seems like some things we can not edit. :)